# How to process out put of diskpart command using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to capture volume number from `diskpart` command output. At present I'm doing it like this:

Using batch script:

```
@echo off
set VOLNO=''
set DRIVE=C
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart') do (
    if %%b==%DRIVE% set VOLNO=%%a
)
echo Volume No. for C Drive is: %VOLNO%
```

Output:

```
Volume No. for C Drive is: 2
```

---

Using PowerShell:

```
$dp = "list volume" | diskpart | ? { $_ -match "^  [^-]" }> 
$dp
```

Output:

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size    Status    Info
Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM        0 B  No Media
Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition   350 MB  Healthy   System
Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition    59 GB  Healthy   Boot
Volume 3     D   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    49 GB  Healthy
```

I want to capture the Volume-Number e.g. it's 2 for C:\ to a variable using PowerShell.

Comment: Why not use the native CMDLETS within Powershell instead of parsing `DISKPART` output?

Comment: @Squashman They weren't introduced until 8.1/10 (can't remember which)

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your regular expression so that you can extract the desired information via capturing groups. I generally recommend building custom objects from the extracted information, to facilitate further processing.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$drive = 'c'

'list volume' | diskpart | Where-Object {
    $_ -match 'Volume (\d+)\s+([a-z])\s+'
} | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'DriveLetter'  = $matches[2]
        'VolumeNumber' = [int]$matches[1]
    }
} | Where-Object {
    $_.DriveLetter -eq $drive
} | Select-Object -Expand VolumeNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise solution that uses `-match` to find the line of interest and the unary form of `-split` to split it into whitespace-separated tokens that can be accessed by index:

```
$drive = 'C'
$volNo = (-split (('list volume' | diskpart) -match " $drive "))[1]
"Volume No. for $drive Drive is: $volNo"
```

Note that `diskpart` must be run from an *elevated* session.